# The use of back button in php

Tags: php

I am very new to the world of PHP . 
The problem that I am facing is with the use of back button . When I click on the back button from page2 to page1 the options which I had selected on page1 is not getting saved . So I need to select all the data once again in page1 . I am using sessions . The funny part is when I use a text box question on page 1 and submit its value to page 2 and then click on back button on page2 the data is being saved . Please take a look into this code
I named this file as 1.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="2.php" method="post">

Name<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>"/>


<input type="submit"  value="next"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

I named this file as 2.php

<?php
session_start();
$name = $_POST['name'];
session_register('name');

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="1.php" method="post">

<input type="submit"  value="back"/>
</form>
</body>
```

The problem is that I do not know how to implement this on the radio buttons . Could you please help me out 
Thanks in advance

Comment: question is about radio buttons or back button??

Comment: Don’t show us the code of what works but of that which doesn’t work.

Comment: you could also try using iframe if you have multiple scripts for your questions.

Comment: @AlphaMale This post is regarding the Back button

Comment: @Gumbo Thankyou for your quick response . I really appreciate it . As I said earlier I am very new to php .  I do not know how to implement the back button for a radio button question so that the data on page1 remains there when I click on the back button from page2. Could you please show me a very small code .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

1.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="2.php" method="post">

Radio1 <input type="radio" name="name" value="radio1" <?php if($_SESSION['name'] == 'radio1') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/><br/>
Radio2 <input type="radio" name="name" value="radio2" <?php if($_SESSION['name'] == 'radio2') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/><br/>
Radio3 <input type="radio" name="name" value="radio3" <?php if($_SESSION['name'] == 'radio3') echo "checked='checked'" ?>/><br/>

<input type="submit"  value="next"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;

?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="1.php" method="post">

<input type="submit"  value="back"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: This is what I exactly needed . Thanks a ton for your help . I really appreiate it . Thank you very much .

Answer (score 2):

If you need a multi-step form, instead submitting each page at once, you can use css to hide and show the prev and next steps, and submit all data at once, this way it will be faster to user because number of times you talk to server also get reduced.

Check [this link](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery/) to know how to create multi step form using css and js

Comment: Hi Sandeep . I am very new to PHP so I am not familiar with css . Could you please help me out by posting a sample code which contains a radio button question instead of a text box . Thanks in advance Sandeep

Comment: added the example link to my answer

Comment: The question was resolved by Sephoy08 . Thankyou for your help Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

With radio buttons, you figure out which one was selected (based on value), and add the `selected` property to it.

However, Sandeep's answer above is better if you can use it.

Comment: Thankyou for your quck response . Could you please show me a sample code by using a radio button question ?thanks in advance

Comment: The question was resolved by Sephoy08 . Thankyou for your help